# Error address space overflow in PSoC Creator

Tags: psoc

I am programming a PSoC3 Microcontroller (CY8C3246PVI-147) via the PSoC Creator 4.4 software.

After adding some functions during compilation I get the following errors:

> *** ERROR L107: ADDRESS SPACE OVERFLOW
>
> ```
> SPACE: CONST
> SEGMENT: ?CO?CYFITTER_CFG
> LENGTH: 00098BH
> ```
>
> *** ERROR L120: CONTENT BELONGS TO ERRONEOUS SEGMENT
>
> ```
> SEGMENT: ?CO?CYFITTER_CFG
> ```
>
> Program Size: data=71.5 xdata=4752 const=2443 code=53415
>
> The command 'LX51.exe' failed with exit code '2'.

In the .map file there is this:

> BASE        START       END         USED      MEMORY CLASS
>
> ==========================================================
>
> X:000000H   X:000000H   X:001FFFH   001290H   XDATA
>
> C:000000H   C:002800H  C:00FFBFH   00D0A7H   CODE
>
> C:000000H   C:002800H   C:00FFBFH   00098BH CONST
>
> I:000000H   I:000000H   I:00007FH   000042H   DATA
>
> I:000020H.0 I:000020H.0 I:00002FH.7 000001H.5 BIT
>
> I:000000H   I:000000H   I:0000FFH   000004H   IDATA

Would anyone be able to advise me on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Well it would seem that you simply used too much memory? I'd look up this PSoC Creator thing but the official site appears to be of "Infinion Quality(tm)" so it takes as long for it to load as it takes for Infinion to deliver components (+/-infinity)...

Comment: Edited your title to match all the other questions on here.